# How to use Bundler and Minifier in deployable web applications and installer projects

Tags: javascript, .net, windows-installer, bundler, minify

This is about how to use Visual Studio 2017 with both Bundler and Minifier and also the "Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension.

My web app has only one main page, so the `<script>` tags are all there on one ASPX page, about 40 of them as there are 40 JS files. When I run bundler and minifier, I want one script tag to point to the bundled and minified JS which is now in one file (and CSS is also bundled from 7 files to one)

When running in release mode I want to use the bundled and minified version so its a simulation of what will be running when live.

When running in debug mode I want to use the unbundled files so I can debug the javascript in the IDE and see the CSS in f12 etc.

I think this means that my one page, a.aspx, has to have two versions ?

When building using the installer projects extension, I want to build only in release mode and that would be using the single bundled JS and CSS files, I don't want the other uncompressed javascript and CSS files shipping in the project even though I want them there when debugging.

How do we go about setting up a project to achieve this ? Is it even possible ? or do people write code to copy out the projects and edit the project files before compilation ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I've temporarily done it by having a container div around the <script> tags with runat=server, and the server then decides whether its debug or release, but it makes my skin crawl to have to put in run time processing for stuff that should be done at compile time.